# collate Latin1_General_CS_AS

Tags: sql

I'm planning on adding 'collate Latin1_General_CS_AS' to my sql code to allow upper and lower case differences but i can't figure out the opposite. now that collate Latin1_General_CS_AS is part of the field, how i can i report if duplicateS exist. ie. customer: TODDj is different that TODDJ.

Comment: I feel some detail is missing. If you want to "allow upper and lower case differences", then `'TODDj'` <> `'TODDJ'`. So why do you want a Case Sensitive collation in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```sql
AND b.customer = LOWER(a.customer)
```

in the where clause.